# Why does tolong not work with a string coming from strcat?

Tags: azure, kql, azure-data-explorer

Why do `tolong(s)` and `tolong(ss)` not produce the same output?

```
let s = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000a';
let ss = strcat('0x', '0000000000000000000000000000000a');
print
    s = s,
    ss = ss,
    s_equal_ss = (s == ss),
    tolong_s = tolong(s),
    tolong_ss = tolong(ss)
```

[image]

---

tl;dr of answer: It's a bug.

Comment: I think this is simply a case where the KQL query parser optimizes conversion of string literals at parse time which can most likely can handle any string length that fits into a valid query. The runtime query engine seems to assume decimal representation and reject any string length > 18 as something that cannot be converted correctly into a 64bit integer. It's arguable whether this is a bug or a feature ;)

Comment: When you send a KQL query to ADX then it needs to "understand" it in order to execute it correctly - this process is usually called parsing. Query parsers tend to have optimizations baked in - in this case when it encounters a literal string like `'0x123'` then it "knows" that this is constant and won't change. So if you have a constant string passed into `tolong()` the it's quite likely the parser will automatically turn this into a number at time of parsing rather than at time of query execution to save computational cost.

Comment: However if you pass this through other functions like `strcat` the parser may not be able to optimize it (even though it could) - it can become a complex problem very quickly to optimize all of these cases. So the conversion is deferred to actual query execution time and which case the ADX query engine probably has some optimization baked in that refuses to even attempt a conversion from string to long if the string is longer than what it considers "sensible"  - in this case more than 18 characters. That being said - this is mostly my guess and the actual reasons might be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does tolong not work with a string coming from strcat?

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my observations:

No, `tolong()` works on `strcat()` (hexadecimal or non-hexadecimal strings whose length should not exceed 18)

**`Example:`**

```
let s = strcat('1', '23');
print(tolong(s));
```

[image]

When you concat with 18 digits or less than that you will get output as i have got:

```
let s = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000a';
let x = strcat('0x', '000000000000000a');
print
    tolong(x),
    tolong(s),
    strlen(x)
```

[image]

More than 18 it is null:

```
let s = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000a';
let x = strcat('0x', '0000000000000000a');
print
    tolong(x),
    tolong(s),
    strlen(x)
```

[image]

When you work with `strcat` on hexadecimal string with more than 18 characters, it gives you null as it cannot convert:

```
let s = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000a';
let x = strcat('0x', '0000000000000000000000000000000a');
print
    tolong(x),
    tolong(s)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I have a hard time following this answer, especially this part: "When you work with strcat on hexadecimal string with more than 18 characters, it gives you null as it cannot convert". For me, `strcat` produces the desired string. Please see the screenshot in my updated question.

Comment: It produces the desired string for me too, yes its true, but when working with tolong() if the input is concatenated string, it only takes 18 characters as max for concatenated one, if you provide directly it works with 18+, this is a bug for tolong() when working with strcat

Comment: **Concatenated string is only allowed till 18 characters in tolong()**  for hexadecimal This is a limitation

Comment: Oh, ok. From your answer it wasn't clear to me that there is a bug. Maybe that should be stated in the answer because it's easy to overlook in the comments.

Comment: @actual_panda it doesn't look like this a specific bug in `strcat` - if you do `let s = substring('0x0000000000000000000000000000000a', 0, 34);` the `tolong` conversion will also fail. So it seems to me that tolong seems to have some special handling when the string converted is const vs dynamic (as returned from a function)